# rails でgem simple calendarがnomethodになって表示されません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsでsimple_calendarを導入する際にno method errorとなってカレンダーの表示ができません。

コントローラーでは@scadulesで変数をhome.html.erbに渡しているはずなのですが何故かエラー表記に
month_calendarと赤い〜線が引かれるだけで誤字や文字違いもなくばどこに原因があるかもう手付かずの状態です。

＊bundleもgemも入っているし他の方の場合はちゃんと反映されているのに何故なのでしょうか?

以下エラーコード

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `month_calendar' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000018790>

            @virtual_path = "pages/home";; @output_buffer.append=  month_calendar do |date| ; @output_buffer.safe_append='
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Did you mean?  month_field):
    1: <%= month_calendar do |date| %>
    2:   <%= date %>
    3: 
    4: 
  
app/views/pages/home.html.erb:1
```

home.html.erb のmonth_calendarが赤い波線で引かれています

```
<%= month_calendar @scadules do |date, scadule| %>
  <%= date %>
<%end%>
```

scapulas_controller.rb

```
class ScadulesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_scadule, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /scadules or /scadules.json
  def index
    @scadules = Scadule.all
  end

  # GET /scadules/1 or /scadules/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /scadules/new
  def new
    @scadule = Scadule.new
  end

  # GET /scadules/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /scadules or /scadules.json
  def create
    @scadule = Scadule.new(scadule_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @scadule.save
        format.html { redirect_to scadule_url(@scadule), notice: "Scadule was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @scadule }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @scadule.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /scadules/1 or /scadules/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @scadule.update(scadule_params)
        format.html { redirect_to scadule_url(@scadule), notice: "Scadule was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @scadule }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @scadule.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /scadules/1 or /scadules/1.json
  def destroy
    @scadule.destroy!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to scadules_url, notice: "Scadule was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_scadule
      @scadule = Scadule.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def scadule_params
      params.require(:scadule).permit(:title, :description, :start_time, :end_time)
    end
end
```

補足
simple_calendarのviewもweek monthそれぞれinstall済みです。
どなたかこの原因不明のエラーを解決していただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。